# I am all attention

Tags: phrases

Is there a phrase in English *I'm all attention* or *I'm all ears*, which indicates that the speaker is listening to the person he/she speaks to very carefully?

Comment: So what's wrong with "I'm all ears" for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the phrase *I'm all ears*, which you have listed, is common in English and means what you're asking.

[I'm all ears:](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I%27m+all+ears)

> You have my attention, so you should talk.
>
> Source: thefreedictionary.com